# how to select first 200 rows in oracle without full table scan

Tags: oracle11g

I need to search first 200 rows in my database with out full table can. If I scan full table it takes too much time because my table contain 160 million record. I am using oracle 11g.

Comment: What do you mean by "first 200 rows"? Is this the order in which rows has been inserted? Is this based on order by a specific column value? "BrokenCrust" has provided a solution - is it a good solution for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to avoid a FTS in this case as I expect

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ROWNUM <= 200;
```

runs pretty fast and starts returning results immediately despite a FTS even with a table containing millions of rows.